# Eloquent update model ambiguous behavior

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have an issue updating my profile/user data. I am using a mixed of template method\chain of responsibility design patterns to begin the updating process in the whole system so that the update process begin within a transaction as if any error occurred everything rolled back. Everything works fine and if any exception happened everything is rolled back, however, the user model is not updated and when logged the query issued by the ORM I find that is did not include the id column/value within the where clause of the update statement while it did for the profile model! The two models are the same. I am using the User model provided by Laravel that extends indirectly from Model class too. I am set primaryKey property in each model to the id column name and also I am letting the default value for the incrementing property as true.

I tried to set the incrementing to false and passing the id value with the updating attributes, however, it did not work too. I am trying to google but I cannot find an answer...

```
class UserUpdateProcessor extends BaseProcessor
{
    private $repository;
    private $reqs;

public function __construct(BaseRepository $repo, $reqsArray)
{
    $this->repository = $repo;
    $this->reqs = $reqsArray;
}

public function Execute()
{
    $handler1 = new UpdateProfiler($this->repository);
    $handler2 = new UpdateAccount($this->repository->helperRepo);
    $handler1->nextHandler = $handler2;

    $handler1->process($this->reqs);
}
}

class UpdateProfiler extends Handler
{
public $nextHandler;
private $repository;
private $keys = [
    'id', 'user_login', 'phone_login', 'user_pass', 'user_email', 'notk'];

public function __construct(BaseRepository $repo)
{
    $this->repository = $repo;
}

public function process($reqsArray)
{
    $this->repository->update(array_diff_key($reqsArray, array_flip($this->keys)),
        $reqsArray[$this->repository->primaryKey]);

    if (!is_null($this->nextHandler) && $this->nextHandler instanceof Handler)
        $this->nextHandler->process($reqsArray);
}
}

class UpdateAccount extends Handler
{
public $nextHandler;
private $repository;
private $keys = [
    'id', 'user_login', 'phone_login', 'user_pass', 'user_email', 'notk'];

public function __construct(BaseRepository $repo)
{
    $this->repository = $repo;
}

public function process($reqsArray)
{
    $this->repository->update(array_intersect_key($reqsArray, array_flip($this->keys)),
        $reqsArray[$this->repository->primaryKey]);

    if (!is_null($this->nextHandler) && $this->nextHandler instanceof Handler)
        $this->nextHandler->process($reqsArray);
}
}

public function update(array $attributes, $id)
{
...
$model = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
$model->fill($attributes);
$model->save(); 
}

string(122) "update `wp_users` set `user_login` = ?, `user_pass` = ?, `user_email` = ?, `notk` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where `id` is null"
array(5) {
[0]=>
string(8) "wp_admin"
[1]=>
string(15) "wp_wordpress123"
[2]=>
string(31) "xyz@example.com"
[3]=>
string(16) "clut0tLDj4ESXftv"
[4]=>
string(19) "2019-01-07 00:55:04"
}
```

The expectation is that when sending the profile/user data to be updated to update them as a one unit. What I am having is that updating the profile data only when I logged the query generated by the ORM I got the above wired sql that tries to update a user with null id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it work. First I had to use the same casing for the primary key as used in the database. Second problem that I was using the default Laravel provided User model and the fillable property defined as protected within it by default. When you are using the Eloquent fill method on a model object then save, the fill method tries to access the fillable property which will be impossible in case it is defined other than public!